# Dropbox Python API Authentication failed And Request Token Not Found

Tags: python, django, dropbox, dropbox-api

This is the part i get the error "Authentication failed".
I am developing a web application and i need some help. I am developing a web app like Project Gutenberg for Turkish books and i want to add "Add to my Dropbox" feature just like in Project Gutenberg. I am using Django as a web framework and here is what i did so far. (Please keep in mind that i am an absolute beginner of Django and a junior software developer so that any suggestions about Django best practices or security issues will be helpful, too.)

This is from book_detail.html

```
<div>
   <form action="/booksite/dropbox_integration/{{book.id}}/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
       <input type="submit" value="Add to Dropbox" />
   </form>
</div>
```

This is my dropbox_integration view:

```
def dropbox_integration(request, book_id):
if request.method == 'POST':
    APP_KEY = 'xxxxxx'  # I have the real values of key and secret in the code
    APP_SECRET = 'xxxxx'
    ACCESS_TYPE = 'app_folder'
    #This is my redirect url after login and upload file
    callback = "http://localhost:8000/booksite/file_upload"

    sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE)
    request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()
    url = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token, oauth_callback=callback)
    #i use session for parameter passing but now this line is useless and irrelevant
    request.session['book_id']=book_id

    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
return HttpResponseRedirect("http://localhost:8000/booksite/")
```

This is my file_upload view:

```
def file_upload(request):
APP_KEY = 'xxx' # i got real key and secret
APP_SECRET = 'xxxx'
ACCESS_TYPE = 'app_folder'

sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE)
b_id=request.session['book_id']

#this line is useless now
book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=1) #book_id
#i want to upload this file to my dropbox as foo1.pdf
f = open('C:/Users/baris/workspace/OpenLibrary/booksite/temp_files/documents/docs/201462912729dt_kitap1.pdf', 'rb')


client1 = client.DropboxClient(sess)
r1 = client1.put_file('foo1.pdf', f)
url="http://localhost:8000/booksite"
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

I click the "Add to Dropbox" button. It redirects me to dropbox and i enter the credentials. Dropbox asks me that i want to give permission to my web site (my app) with buttons allow and deny. I click deny. Page is loading, loading, loading... and i get error:

```
Exception Type:     ErrorResponse
Exception Value:    [401] u'Authentication failed'
Django Version:     1.6.5
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/booksite/file_upload?oauth_token=some_real_token&uid=some_number
```

Thanks, in advance.

**Update July 7, 2014**

This is the part i get the error "Request token not found".

This is the dropbox_integration view:

```
def dropbox_integration(request, book_id):
    APP_KEY = 'xxx' #i got real values
    APP_SECRET = 'xxx'
    ACCESS_TYPE = 'app_folder'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        base_path=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        config_path=os.path.join(os.path.join(base_path, 'temp_files'), "config.txt")
        logger.debug("Base path="+base_path)
        logger.debug("Config path="+config_path)
        content=[]
        if os.path.exists(config_path):
            logger.debug("Config.txt var")
            with open(config_path) as the_file:
                content = the_file.readlines()
        else:
            logger.debug("Config.txt yok")
            with open(config_path, 'w') as the_file:
                the_file.write(APP_KEY)
                the_file.write('|')
                the_file.write(APP_SECRET)

        config_key=content[0].split('|')[0]
        config_secret=content[0].split('|')[1]

        callback = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/booksite/file_upload"

        sess = session.DropboxSession(config_key, config_secret, ACCESS_TYPE)
        request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()
        request.session['request_token']=json.dumps(request_token.__dict__)
        logger.debug("req_ses="+request.session['request_token'])

        url = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token, oauth_callback=callback)

        request.session['book_id']=book_id

        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("http://127.0.0.1:8000/booksite/")
```

This is the file_upload view:

```
@csrf_protect   
def file_upload(request):
    base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    config_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(base_path, 'temp_files'), "config.txt")
    logger.debug("Base path=" + base_path)
    logger.debug("Config path=" + config_path)
    content = []
    if os.path.exists(config_path):
        with open(config_path) as the_file:
           content = the_file.readlines()
    else:
        logger.debug("Config.txt dosyasi bulunamadi.")

    config_key = content[0].split('|')[0]
    config_secret = content[0].split('|')[0]

    ACCESS_TYPE = 'app_folder'

    sess = session.DropboxSession(config_key, config_secret, ACCESS_TYPE)
    b_id = request.session['book_id']
    logger.debug("File upload fonksiyonu book id=" + str(b_id))

    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=1)  # book_id olarak 1 verdim.
    request_token = JSONDecoder(object_hook=from_json).decode(request.session['request_token'])
    logger.debug("REQUEST_TOKEN="+str(request_token))
    access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)
    logger.debug(access_token)
    client1 = client.DropboxClient(sess)
    try:
        base_path1 = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        with open(os.path.join(base_path1, "udacity.txt"), "rb") as fh:  # os.path.join(self.path, self.filename)
             path = os.path.join(path, filename)
             print path
             print fh
             res = client1.put_file("udacity.txt", fh)
    except Exception, e:
        logger.debug("ERROR: " + str(e))

    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/booksite/books/12/detail/"
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

This is my helper from_json function:

```
def from_json(json_object):
    secret=""
    key=""
    if 'secret' in json_object:
        secret=json_object['secret']
    if 'key' in json_object:
        key=json_object['key']
    logger.debug(secret+" ---- "+key)
    return session.OAuthToken(json_object['secret'], json_object['key'])
```

I get an error at the line sess.obtain_access_token(request_token) in file_upload view.
I can't get an access_token and get error "Request Token Not Found". What is the reason?
This is my Django log:

```
[06/Jul/2014 15:38:15] DEBUG [booksite.views:133] File upload function book id=12
[06/Jul/2014 15:38:15] DEBUG [booksite.views:164] xxxxx---- xxxx
[06/Jul/2014 15:38:15] DEBUG [booksite.views:137] REQUEST_TOKEN=<dropbox.session.OAuthToken object at 0x028BCB90>
```

Comment: The "Request Token Not Found" error message is the Dropbox server telling you that it doesn't recognize the request token value you passed up, so to trouble shoot that I'd start by manually inspecting the actual key and secret values on your request_token object are what you expect. (E.g., compare the key against the one in the /authorize URL where you authorize the app)

Comment: Thanks. concepts like request token, access token, key, secret etc. are really confusing. I think i need to start with a theoretical oauth tutorial, because i got stucked for a couple of days.

Comment: There's a basic tutorial here that might be useful to understand the concepts: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/20/using-oauth-in-plaintext-mode

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is because Django cannot find the **Cross Site Request Forgery** protection for `{% csrf_token %}` you using in your form. For sure you have to add it because of security reasons...

To add security for Cross Site Request Forgery you have to add the following decorator to your view:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt, csrf_protect

@csrf_protect
#@csrf_exempt says to make an exemption on csrf, but of course is not secure.
#@csrf_exempt
def file_upload(request):
    ...
```

For more details please read [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/)

Comment: thanks for your help. i tried it but there is another problem in the code related with the dropbox api. i am updating my question.